# Delete a parent record using .Remove inside entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following model classes inside asp.net mvc web application.

```
public partial class Country
    {
        public Country()
        {
            this.Depts = new HashSet<Dept>();
        }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryNAme { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Dept> Depts { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public partial class Dept
    {
        public Dept()
        {
            this.Emps = new HashSet<Emp>();
        }

        public int DeptID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OptionalCountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Emp> Emps { get; set; }
    }
```

now let say i want to delete a Parent country object and set the related countryID FK inside the Dept table as null. so seems i can do so using any of these approaches:-

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Country country = db.Countries.Single(a=>a.CountryID == id);
            foreach(var c in country.Depts.ToList())
            {
                country.Depts.Remove(c);


            }
         db.Countries.Remove(country);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and this will have the same result:-

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Country country = db.Countries.Include(a=>a.Depts).Single(a=>a.CountryID == id);

            db.Countries.Remove(country);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

so are there any differences between the two methods, as seems both will delete the Parent object and set the CountryID FK as null insdie the Dept table ?

Comment: EF is cascading the deletes for the associated objects; the first code example is just doing unnecessary work that EF would have done for you as you discovered in the second code sample.

Comment: @BradRem but let say i set Cascade to be false how this will affect the two approaches ? and is Cascade inside EF is the same as the Cascade we use inside sql server databases ?

Comment: I believe Cascade in EF is the same as Cascade in SQL Server. If you were using a foreign key in Depts that was NOT nullable, then there would be a difference in the two methods because SQL server would attempt to remove the Depts record when you removed the referenced Country record; without Cascade, you would get the exception since Depts must point to a Country.

Comment: but if i try this " db.Countries.Remove(country);" and the Cascade is set to True. then EF should not try to remove the child Depts unless i have explicitly add .Include(a=>a.Depts) inside the country object, as i am doing in my second approach is this correct ? i mean the delete object should have the required child records attached to it ...

Comment: It seems like you have a more specific question about how something in EF is not working as you expected; you should just ask it instead of what is amounting to this scattershot question and answer session. Also, since the key is nullable, I don't believe under any circumstance will Depts get deleted when you delete a Country.

Answer (score 0):

in EntityFramework you can set he Cascading Delete as true/false.

**`If its true`**
 then both method doing the same job.. in first one you are doing the job of EF, even still EF will check if child exist to delete, while in Second EF doing its job as it defined..

**`If its false`**
 then both are different.. first one is the right approach to delete child first then parent.. while second will just delete the parent on the child entities..

**By Default Cascading Delete is True**

Comment: but if i set Cascades Delete to be false, then i think my second approach will raise an exception if the parent record have child ,, and it will not just delete the parent on the child entities, as you mentioned.. can u adivce?

Comment: did you try and faced the exception you mentioned?? as you have set the nullable country id so might not get that..